# What do people say when someone posts an old meme picture

Tags: single-word-requests, internet

What would one say in English when someone posts a picture or meme that one has already seen?  The response would be something like 'Already seen! Dissapointed!" in one word.

Comment: The usual refrain is ***repost!***.

Comment: **Recycling** it?

Comment: @DanBron Repost is the single correct answer; it's opposite is Original Content. Your comment should be the accepted answer (except the question's closed).

Answer (score 2):

I would call it ***old news***:

> ***[old news](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/old_news)***
>
> NOUN
>
> A person or thing considered to be no longer of interest, relevance, or importance, especially through over-familarity.

Urban Dictionary agrees:

> ***[Old news](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Old%20news)***
>
> Piss the other party off, by saying "Old news".
>   People saying "Old news" refer to the fact that they already know what you were trying to tell them.

and gives this example:

> Guy 1: Yo.. check this out (sending a link)
>   Guy 2: Old news, bro.
>   Guy 1: Ahh... Fuck you!

Hope this helps!